# AVAudioRecorder hasn't sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

i have a problem with `AVAudioPlayer` in **Some Condition**.
in first my audio recorder working Fine generally. but after VOIP call and play ring from `built_in_Speaker` and work many with audio session , after hangup the call ,i can't record Audio with sound in first! but in second time every thing working fine.
**Problem**

in condition that i have mentioned  my audio was record but hasn't voice!

i want to know in which situation maybe it happen?

```
 self.audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;
[self.audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
if(err){
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}

BOOL preparedToRecord = [self.audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
__block BOOL recordStarted = NO;

err = nil;
[self.audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
if(err){
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}

if (preparedToRecord){
    recordStarted = [self.audioRecorder record];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved**

i have found the reason of this problem.
i have addObserve my self to catch the notification of AVAudioSession, and check the `AudioSession` interrupt/RoutChanging!
the problem is after my call i have try to change audio route to speaker but a class that addobserved for AudioRoutChanging notification try to prevent that. so  the audio session route change every second and couldn't record the audio.

**Conclusion**
you should do like this for recording the audio:

1) sure about **permission**

```
2)[self.audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];

3)[self.audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
```

4) sure about your  **route** don't be change during recording.

4)sure about your destination patch

Answer (score -1):

Recording audio requires explicit permission from the user. The first time your app’s audio session attempts to use an audio input route while using a category that enables recording, the system automatically prompts the user for permission. You can explicitly ask earlier by calling the requestRecordPermission: method. Until the user grants your app permission to record, your app can record only silence.

refer here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html

Comment: i have get the permission in first launch of app , and i have mentioned i use audio session in my call and it is working fine!
i fix the problem i explained here soon.
tnx for your reply!